# footnote under the table moves it right

Tags: footnotes

I know this topic was already mentioned but I still can not use your advices in a proper way. I wanted to have footnotes under the table instead of at the bottom of the page. I changed the `table` environment for `minipage` because `\footnote` command wasn't working, meaning that the footnotes were not showed uder the table at all. Now they are visible but the table was moved to the right side :(. Could you help me, please ?

```
\begin{table}[ht!]
\centering
\caption {Parameters of the AD and the GFI alternative scenarios}
\begin{minipage}{7cm}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l | l | l l} 
\toprule 
\multirow{2}{*}{Parameter} & \multirow{2}{*}{unit} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Alternative >scenario} \\ \cline{3-4}
\phantom{aaa} & \phantom{aaa} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{AD} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{GFI} \\ 
\midrule 
Electricity efficiency  & \% & 45\footnote{InSource Energy Limited, 2010} & \phantom{aaaa} >26 \\ 
Heat efficiency  & \% & 51 & \phantom{aaaa} 73 \\ 
Water content of digestate & \% ww & 75\footnote{Danish Energy Agency, 2010} & \phantom{aaaa} - \\ \midrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\label{alternativescenario_ad_gfi}
\end{table}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is not the footnote, but the 7cm minipage (why 7cm?)

If you use `\textwidth` your tabular is centered in the page.

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow} 

\begin{document}

\section{With parbox}
\begin{table}[ht!]
\centering
\caption {Parameters of the AD and the GFI alternative scenarios}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth} % <-- use the complete width, not only 7cm
%0.7\textwidth is maybe better.
\centering  %<-- center inside the minipage
\begin{tabular}{l | l | l l} 
\toprule 
\multirow{2}{*}{Parameter} & \multirow{2}{*}{unit} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Alternative >scenario} \\ \cline{3-4}
\phantom{aaa} & \phantom{aaa} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{AD} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{GFI} \\ 
\midrule 
Electricity efficiency  & \% & 45\footnote{InSource Energy Limited, 2010} & \phantom{aaaa} >26 \\ 
Heat efficiency  & \% & 51 & \phantom{aaaa} 73 \\ 
Water content of digestate & \% ww & 75\footnote{Danish Energy Agency, 2010} & \phantom{aaaa} - \\ \midrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\label{alternativescenario_ad_gfi}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

If you want the footnotes under the tabular and not on the left , you may adapt the width to `0.7\textwidth`.